# Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement login with Facebook using Firebase Authentication so I followed all the steps

so first I added FacebookActivity in my AndroidManifest :

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

second I added login button to my Fragment :

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_login_facebook"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

and finally this is my following code :

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton btn_login_facebook = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_login_facebook);
    btn_login_facebook.setReadPermissions("email");
    btn_login_facebook.setFragment(this);
    btn_login_facebook.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess:");
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCancel: ");
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onError: ");
        }
    });
```

and I followed all the steps to add Facebook SDK and Facebook App ID on https://developers.facebook.com

so the problem here is when I start the app it cracked and I got this error :

> Process: com.th3codefather.www.tripexp, PID: 21998
>                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.th3codefather.www.tripexp/com.th3codefather.www.tripexp.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58: Error
>   inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58:
>   Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.th3codefather.www.tripexp.LoginFragment.onCreateView(LoginFragment.java:54)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
>                                                                                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6005)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.th3codefather.www.tripexp.LoginFragment.onCreateView(LoginFragment.java:54) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6005) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>                                                                                   Caused by: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call
>   FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.
>                                                                                      at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:145)
>                                                                                      at com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker.(AccessTokenTracker.java:55)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2.(LoginButton.java:563)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.configureButton(LoginButton.java:563)
>                                                                                      at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.(FacebookButtonBase.java:64)
>                                                                                      at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.(LoginButton.java:201)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.th3codefather.www.tripexp.LoginFragment.onCreateView(LoginFragment.java:54) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6005) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialization:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

should be done before setting the content view.

If you do:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

before the intialization, the Facebook button won't be inflated into the activity.

Comment: That's how i solved my problem,Thank you the answer.